# nested routes mapping

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

This is the setup that I have

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure 'plurals',
  child: 'children'

App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'people', ->
    @resource 'person', path: ':person_id', ->
      @route 'children'

App.PerosnChidlrenRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.PerosnChidlren.find()
```

So, there is two problems here: first is that PersonChildren hitting /person_childrens instead of /people/:person_id/children.
And the second is incorrect pluralization as you can mention:) 
Can you please explain how do I setup routing and pluralization correctly?

p.s. I've tried to put everything up in http://jsfiddle.net/UJkn3/1/

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but try `@route 'children', path: ':person_id/children'` for the route map, and maybe in the route change `model: (params) -> App.PerosnChidlren.find(params.person_id)`

Comment: Hmmm... this _may be_ a working solution, but now I have a different problem in people template:
    {{#each person in controller}}
      {{#linkTo 'person.children' person class='ten columns panel'}}
giving me an 'Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.'

Comment: this is actually not the correct solution because in the `find` I said to pass `params.person_id`, when in fact you'll have to do a `filter`. In regards to the template issue, I've seen this error message before but I can't remember what was the context and how I solved it.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle with a few minor things: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/UJkn3/6/  One thing tho, this is **not** gonna work in JS fiddle because you're using the RESTAdapter. You can't fire AJAX requests to a different server like that. Can you try using the FixtureAdapter?

Comment: Yeah, sure I can add fixtures, just need to sleep now, but will it work on JSFiddle anyways? :\ 
I've figured out that route now is http://localhost:3000/#/people/1/1/children, and it's hitting http://localhost:3000/person_childrens/1,
so find(params.person_id) might be a part of the solution, he he ;)

Comment: Not really sure if this helps, but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ABJN7/) has a 3 levels router. Not really good tho, just thought of posting here

Comment: Yeah, the prolem is the url mappings, so this won't help much in particular case, though still a good example for using fixtures and I'll keep it.
But maybe it's everything well with ember? Maybe I should dig an ember-data? I'll give this a chance.